# frequently update android widget

Tags: android

I m creating an android widget of a random number.. it is working fine..but i want to update this number after 1 seconds... but it is not possible ..please help..here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
for(int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){
int appWidgetId= appWidgetIds[i];
Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
RemoteViews views=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);

Random r=new Random();
int randomInt=r.nextInt(10);
String rand=String.valueOf(randomInt);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,rand);

final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 1000;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

}
}
}
```

Comment: consider using service to update Widget...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you may solve this issue anyway i just paste my code

**1) AppWidgetProvider**

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        String number = String.format("%03d", (new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, number);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.aaa.bbb.REQUEST_WIDGET_UPDATE"))
    {
        //ComponentName, RemoteViews and AppWidgetManager
        ComponentName provider = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_widget);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());

        //Change the TextView value
        //String timeLeft = intent.getStringExtra("timeLeft");

        String number = String.format("%03d", (new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, number);

        //Update the widget
        manager.updateAppWidget(provider, views);
    }
    else
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

}

**2) MainActivity**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BroadcastReceiver br = new SimpleWidgetProvider();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction("com.aaa.bbb.REQUEST_WIDGET_UPDATE");
    this.registerReceiver(br, filter);


    new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.aaa.bbb.REQUEST_WIDGET_UPDATE");
            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.aaa.bbb.REQUEST_WIDGET_UPDATE");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }.start();



}
```

}

**3) AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="SimpleWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.aaa.bbb.REQUEST_WIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/simple_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```